# How is it possible that some celestial bodies have icy surfaces when water boils off at any temperature in absolute vacuum?

Tags: water, sublimation, evaporation

Why doesn't the ice on comets or on the moon Enceladus sublime? Enceladus doesn't have an atmosphere, so what is it that prevents Enceladus' water ice surface from becoming a gas? Did I miss something?

Comment: Ice sublimes, it does not boil. It is very slow process at low T, slowing down like exponentially with T. 
[Nature 2005: Atmosphere found on Enceladus](https://www.nature.com/articles/news050314-15)

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you. There's still the question why tiny comets don't sublime around their aphelions though. How long would it take for a 1 mile (1.6 km) diameter comet to sublime (disregarding their evaporation in proximity of the Sun)?

Comment: See also https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ice-thermal-properties-d_576.html   for table and chart of progressive decrease of vapor pressure. Enceladus noon t  (of static surface) is reportedly near -190 °C.

Comment: And once some comes off, the partial pressure at the surface is no longer zero.

Comment: For a comet at aphelion? Much longer than the age of the universe.

Comment: Technically all solids have some equilibrium vapor pressure, but it's usually negligible.